# How to use Yojson to parse a JSON file?

Tags: json, ocaml

can anyone help me in regards to parsing a json file using Yojson? I can't find any examples online. I'm kind of confused as to how yojson works...

http://mjambon.com/yojson-doc/Yojson.Safe.html

Isn't too helpful. Can anyone link me to a simple example of yojson? thanks!

I just want to start simple...like read in a json file and just spit the entire thing back out.

Comment: If your goal the is just to read a json file and spit it back you may want to use (self-advertisement) [jsonm](http://erratique.ch/software/jsonm/). The first [example](http://erratique.ch/software/jsonm/doc/Jsonm#examples) shows how to do it.

Comment: Yojson is not meant to be used directly, but rather as the runtime for [atdgen](https://mjambon.github.io/atdgen-doc/) so you can focus on writing code that matters.

Answer (score 3):

How about looking at the `examples` subdirectory in the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is rather transparent. The obvious approach is to use `to_string` and `from_string`.

Comment: Where is the documentation ? I only see a README.md and source code.

Comment: The documentation doesn't include setup instructions, AFAICT.